# MicroProfile LRA on Wildfly - How to setup LRA coordinator host and port on client application runing on WildFly

Tags: wildfly, microprofile, eclipse-microprofile-config

I have introduced LRA on a MicroProfile application already running on WildFly AS.

To get the LRA working I have added the following depedency on my application pom.xml

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.narayana.rts</groupId>
    <artifactId>narayana-lra</artifactId>
    <version>5.10.6.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

and I have created an LRA coordinator running on the same host ad listening on port 8080.

The application works as expected.

Now I want to move LRA coordinator on a remote host, but I'm not able to configure my application to point to it (on new host and port).

I have tried to put in my microprofile-config.properties the following parameters:

`mp.lra.http.host=<new_host>`

`mp.lra.http.port=<new_port>`

but without effect.

Can anyone suggest me hot to configure LRA coordinator host and port on client application?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Narayana doesn't support MicroProfile Config yet even if it is something that it probably should. The properties you want to set are defined only as system properties (i.e., read with `System.getProperty(String, String)`.

Another issue is that the properties you are looking for are defined as `lra.http.host` and `lra.http.port` respectively. MP LRA made a deliberate decision to remove all coordinator references from the specification to not specify the implementation architectures (saga can also be implemented as an orchestration pattern).

So you need to set these system properties for instance when you are starting the WildFly server:

```
bin/standalone.sh -Dlra.http.host=lra-coordinator.com -Dlra.http.port=7777
```

Finally, if you ever move to the latest Narayana releases, these properties were merged only into single property `lra.coordinator.url` which is however still read only from system properties.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your explanation. In fact I resolved by adding        <property name="lra.http.host" value="<new_host>"/>
        <property name="lra.http.port" value="<new_port>"/> in the standaone.sh

Comment: Sure, it just needs to be defined as a system property. However, I will work on making it an MP config property too, hopefully soon.

Comment: Now I have put my lra-coordinator (running locally on my PC on windows platform) in docker container and I'm facing this error:  LRARecord.doEnd put http://localhost:8080/primami-operation-persona/api/lra3/complete?method=javax.ws.rs.PUT failed

Comment: Unfortunately, that's too little information for me to understand the problem. Maybe docker network. But without more information I can't be sure.

Comment: 1. I have built a Quarkus LRA coordinator (with narayana 5.10.0.Final version)
2. I have built a SAGA example running on WildFly 23.0.2. The SAGA example is correclty working. 
3. Then I moved the LRA coordinator on Docker and my SAGA example doesn't work anymore.
4. The POST actions is correctly called as per WildFly log:
... starting ONE - context http://0.0.0.0:8085/lra-coordinator/0_ffffac140002_90c7_62545e4d_2
5. but from LRA coordinator docker log I see:
... LRARecord.doEnd put http://localhost:8080/primami-operation-persona/api/lra1/complete?method=javax.ws.rs.PUT failed

Comment: I think the issue is that LRA coordinator from docker container calls the completing/compensate action by referrig it as running on "localhost" ...

Comment: Yes, this is what I meant by docker network.If coordinator registers service on localhost:8080 (this is what service tells the coordinator) and coordinator later tries to call localhost, this localhost is inside the container, not on the running machine, especially on windows with docker runner interface which is even more complex. Maybe try something like this - https://www.cloudsavvyit.com/14114/how-to-connect-to-localhost-within-a-docker-container/.

Comment: Ok, but in a cloud environment in which coordinator and participants run on different pods, it is needed that each participant register itself with its URI. Otherwise, how the coordinator distinguishes betwee different participants ? I have just written this Question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71838625/microprofile-lra-how-to-define-custom-participant-uri-on-a-wildfly-jee-applica